# request wifi and lte on same time in android

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, lte

I have to use WiFi and lte at the same time on Android.

Using ConnectivityManager,  I was able to send a request via lte while wifi was active

However, I never used the two at the same time.

I currently use these methods.

```
private static ConnectivityManager cm;
private static NetworkRequest.Builder req;

cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
req = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
req.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
req.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
cm.requestNetwork(req.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        //here you can use bindProcessToNetwork
        cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can request wifi and lte at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onAvailable() of NetworkCallback to check for network changes.
In addition, bindProcessToNetwork() declares that only certain networks will be used.
Use ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworks() with the my simple example below.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network []networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
for(int i = 0 ; i < networks.length ; i++) {
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(networks[i]);
    if(info.getTypeName().equals("MOBILE")) {
        // This is mobile network (3G/LTE)
        // Use networks[i].bindSocket(java.net.Socket) for low-level socket communication
        // Use networks[i].openConnection(java.net.URL) for HTTP request
    }
    else if(info.getTypeName().equals("WIFI")) {
        // This is WiFi network
        // Use networks[i].bindSocket(java.net.Socket) for low-level socket communication
        // Use networks[i].openConnection(java.net.URL) for HTTP request

    }
    else {
        // This is another network (WIFI_P2P, Ethernet, Bluetooth, ...)
    }
}
```